# FFMPEG: Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_adelay_9

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i $FILE0 -i $FILE1 -filter_complex \
       "[0]pad=2*iw:1*ih[l];[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+$DIFFs1/TB[1v]; [l][1v]overlay=x=W/2[v]; \
        [1]adelay=$DIFFms1|$DIFFms1[1a]; \
        [0][1a]amix=inputs=2[a]" \
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" $OUT
```

I was trying to merge two files side-by-side with a significant time gap, which I had computed using $DIFF, $DIFFS and $DIFFms. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_adelay_9
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #3:0
```

P.S.: FILE0 and FILE1 have been inputted before.

Comment: What is the actual command, without the variables, being executed? Show the complete log.

Comment: ffmpeg complains about decoding stream `#3:0` but your command only shows 2 inputs. The actual command would have atleast 4. Add -report to generate a debug report.